# Warning on using project.parent.version as the version of a module in Maven 3

Tags: maven, maven-3

In maven multi-module projects where I want each of the modules to always keep the same version as the parent, I've typically done something like the following in the module's pom.xml:

```xml
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
  <name>name</name>
```

Since I started using maven 3.0-alpha-5, I get the following warning for doing so.

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.groupid.artifactId:name:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.groupid.artifactId:name::${project.parent.version}, /Users/whaley/path/to/project/child/pom.xml
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
```

I'm curious to know what the real problem with tying a module's version to the parent version is, if any?  Or is this a case of a general warning when any expression, regardless of whether it's project.parent.version, is used for the version element.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

> I'm curious to know what the real problem with tying a module's version to the parent version is, if any? Or is this a case of a general warning when any expression, regardless of whether it's project.parent.version, is used for the version element.

Well, that would be easy to test. Because I was curious, I just did it for you using the following pom:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>module</artifactId>
  <version>${myversion}</version>
  <name>module</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <myversion>1.0-SNAPSHOT</myversion>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

And maven is indeed complaining:

```
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.mycompany:module:${myversion}, /home/pascal/Projects/maven-maven3-testcase/module/pom.xml
```

To be honest, I think that maven is right here, it doesn't make much sense to use a property for the `<version>` element (at least not for project.version) and it's nice to have maven complaining about it.

And if you want to use the parent pom version in sub-modules, **just remove the `<version>` tag from the child poms**, they will inherit the version from the parent. What you are currently doing is unnecessary.

Comment: Just seeing your bolded answer documented here:  http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance .  It was mentioned that way in Maven: The Definitive guide, but I glossed over that at the time I read it.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: The examples in http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4715 seem to have some valid reasons for using a property for the <version> element, so I'm not convinced there's no use for that, but +1 for reminding us that in the case you want submodules to use the parent pom version, just remove the tag and let inheritance work.

Comment: As of Spring Roo 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT if you remove the `<version>`-tag from a child pom, it would start complaining that `Version is required for ...`. But that's Spring Roo's fault, not Maven's. Maven is working just fine without the version-tag.

Comment: That's stupid :-(. How do I use ${buildNumber} from buildnumber-maven-plugin in version?

Comment: No! In Maven version 3.2.1 remove the version tag from the child poms, result in 'project build error: parent.version is missing'

Comment: @shanyangqu Is right, the answer is wrong. You cannot remove the <version> tag that lies in the <parent> tag.

Comment: @shanyangqu. Just to be clear here. You are correct to say that you can't remove the version from the *parent* section of the child pom. That's needed to specify the parent that you're inheriting from. But you *can* leave out the version of the child itself. It will default to the parent.version (the version in the parent section).

Comment: @drrob so how to get rid of those nasty Maven warnings in such a case?  While I'm releasing new versions I want to have my child modules always use the latest parent version. That's why I'm using a property for the version in the parent tag. And Maven is complaining about it. How can one get rid of those warnings?

Comment: @masi hardcode the version number in the parent section, don't use a property. Then use the release and versions plugins to update all modules

Comment: Also, parent is a relative concept : who is the parent in your <version> tag when is extended once again ? it is the parent of the n+2 child, or the parent of the n+1 child (where it was declared) ? Depending on how maven handle inheritance, you could get unexpected result.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. For each child project we need to set parent pom's version. Fortunately this is only a warning and maven is compiling.

Comment: You can also visit this maven page,even maven documentation offer this option but gives warning :) https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html#Multi_Module_Setup

Answer (score 23):

I might be late here to discuss on this. I got a simple solution for this `WARNING`.

First of all, if you want that all child modules will take same version as parent, then you just remove `<version>` tag from child POM and as you include `<parent>` in child POM, that should be there.

In absence of `<version>` in child POM, it will automatically take Parent POM `version`.

Now if you want to use `property` in parent POM version and want to get the same in all child-modules, you can go through as follow.

There is no limitation on using property in `<version>` part of parent or child POM. But if you use your own xml tag for specifying that or you use your own property, then `WARNING` comes, (although this is just warning, everything works as expected).

But if you want to get rid of this `WARNING`, you can follow these steps:

1. Create `<properties>` inside POM.xml as below

   ```
   <properties>
       <revision>1.0.0</revision>  <!-- Put your version -->
   </properties>
   ```
2. In `<version>` of the POM.xml, put as follow

   ```
   <version>${revision}</version>
   ```

Sample code snippet (for multi-module project):

```
<groupId>abc.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>pqr</artifactId>
<!-- <version>1.0.0</version> -->
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<description>Parent POM</description>

<properties>
    <revision>1.0.0</revision>
</properties>
```

**Note**: Instead of `<revision>`, if you use any other name (for example, `<my.version>`), you will face that `WARNING`

Now if you want to pass version during `mvn deploy`, you can use `mvn deploy "-Drevision=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"` and similarly for `mvn install` also.

Now if above configuration, you want to use as Parent POM, and you want to use same `version` in all child module, that can also be done. In each `child module POM`, use below

```
<parent>
    <groupId>abc.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>1.0.0</version> -->
    <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>

<groupId>abc.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>Child</artifactId>
<!-- <version>1.0.0</version> -->     <!-- Automatically inherit parent POM version -->
<name>Demo</name>
```

For reference, you can go through [maven multi module setup](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html#Multi_Module_Setup)

Comment: Do you know why using the revision as variable name does not give warning? Does it has any special significance?

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya Check out the link at the end of this answer, it mentions the three placeholders (including this one) that are specifically allowed for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the warning is correct. See [MNG-4717](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4715): "the pom that gets deployed will not have the property value resolved, so
anyone depending on that pom will pick up the dependency as being the
string uninterpolated with the ${ } and much hilarity will ensue in your
build process." "However, if one uses flatten-maven-plugin the deployed pom gets a resolved value."

Answer (score -1):

I have a multi-module app. In the sub-module, I changed

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.microservices</groupId>
        <artifactId>microservices</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
   </parent>
```

to

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.microservices</groupId>
        <artifactId>microservices</artifactId>
        <version>{parent.version}</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
   </parent>
```

That fixed it for me.

Comment: That should be `${parent.version}`, not `{parent.version}`.  And this seems to be a different case than that of the OP.  All that said, this isn't a good idea.  The child has to reference a specific parent, otherwise that parent can't be looked up deterministically.  `parent.version` might be set to the right thing in the current reactor, during a current build, but as soon as you use this artifact in another project Maven will resolve `parent.version` to the version of _that other project_.