# Why does Maven 3 give up supporting application $version declaration?

Tags: maven-2, versioning, version, maven, maven-3

As you see from the title, I want to ask that the case of in [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) 3 there is no support for `$version` in `pom.xml` anymore. Do we have to really write a constant every time in each project in every `pom.xml` and related configuration files again and again? How can we avoid doing this? How can we use a versioning method like `$version`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The expression `${version}` is deprecated, you should use `${project.version}` instead, but both are still supported and you certainly don't need a custom property.

The following just works fine for me with Maven 3:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>services</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <type>ejb</type>
</dependency>
```

And also have a look at my previous answer to [Warning on using project.parent.version as the version of a module in Maven 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981151/warning-on-using-project-parent-version-as-the-version-of-a-module-in-maven-3/1982027#1982027), the way you're using `version` (based on what I saw in the comments in another answer) doesn't make much sense IMHO and Maven 3 actually kindly suggests to follow a best practice. Just inherit the version.

Answer (score 1):

Using a macro inside the top `<version/>` element and the version in the `<parent/>` element never worked in maven 2. It appeared to work, but caused nothing but confusion downstream. If that's not what you are talking about, please clarify your question.

Comment: I am talking about <version>${projectVersion}</version> declaration. Instead of, say, writing the version like <version>0.0.1</version> we could write ${projectVersion} before, but in maven3, it does not support it. I understand it from the warning it gives right on the clean-install time. On the console, it clearly says "version must be a constant". However, before maven3 it never warned like that. So, in maven3, the ${projectVersion} declaration (for my example) between the version tags is not supported anymore.

As a result, is there any idea or a method that enables me to use it again?

Comment: In what content? In an ordinary dependency or inside <parent>?

Comment: Where is the problem with ${project.version} usually you don't need. If you release a new version it will automatically replace the old versions with the new ones. So i don't see the need for a macro?

Comment: Hi again, here it is what inside of the top pom.xml;
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.mp.myproject</groupId>
 <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
 <name>myproject Maven Main</name>
 <packaging>pom</packaging> 
 <properties>
  <projectVersion>2.3</projectVersion>
 </properties>
 <version>${projectVersion}</version>
...
<modules>
  <module>../myproject_domain</module>
  <module>../myproject_ejb</module> 
  <module>../myproject_web</module>
  <module>../myproject_ear</module> 
 </modules>

Comment: Ok, and the other pom.xml's in the modules there are:
<parent>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.mp.myproject</groupId>
  <version>${projectVersion}</version>
  <relativePath>../myproject/pom.xml</relativePath>
 </parent>

Answer (score 0):

The error below shows the deprecation of `$(artifactId}` and `${version}`

> [WARNING] The expression ${artifactId} is deprecated. Please use
>   ${project.artifactId} instead. [WARNING] The expression ${version} is
>   deprecated. Please use ${project.version}  instead. [WARNING]
>   [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they
>   threaten t he stability of your build. [WARNING] [WARNING] For this
>   reason, future Maven versions might no longer support buildin g such
>   malformed projects.

The warning message spells it out. Replace `${artifactId}` with `${project.artifactId}`, and `${version}` with `${project.version}`