# Is there a way to cascade the version of a parent pom?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a root pom.xml that acts as a parent for several child pom.xml files, which is great if you have one or two child pom.xml files. I am working on a project that has 50+ child pom.xml files, and several releases going on at once. Everything is great until I need to update the version of the parent pom.xml files, which can be tedious. Is there a way to cascade the version of the parent pom.xml down to all child pom.xml files?

I had the idea to just create a property in the parent pom.xml for the current version, but that's not working.

**EDIT**

Here is a sample from my child pom.xml files:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>  <!-- This is the value that I would like to parameterize in my child pom.xmls -->
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

As an aside, I am using Maven 3.0.3

Comment: Looks like this has been asked before... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981151/warning-on-using-project-parent-version-as-the-version-of-a-module-in-maven-3

Comment: @DaveRlz Almost, but not quite

Comment: There's a bit in the response that says 'to use the parent pom version in sub-modules, just remove the <version> tag from the child poms, they will inherit the version from the parent.' Isn't that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @DaveRlz I tried using just a groupId, artifactId and relativePath, but maven doesn't like it

Comment: Just use the versions-maven-plugin as i described in my answer.

Comment: @khmarbaise - Reading up on it now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

Have an aggregator POM project, in which you specify all your child modules and then run this goal on the this aggregator project:

```
mvn versions:update-parent
```

This will update all child modules with the new parent version.

Alternatively you can use the same before each release:prepare goal of your child module, thus avoiding creating the aggregator module.

So in case you want to release a child module, you just run this goal:

```
mvn versions:update-parent release:prepare
```

This will ensure that the parent gets updated with a new version before it is being prepared for a release.

I read in your comment you are missing an scm tag. Example of usage in case of subversions might be:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://your.domain/scm/svn/yourModule/trunk/</developerConnection>
</scm>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <tagBase>https://your.domain/scm/svn/yourModule/tags</tagBase>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Release plugin does not work without a properly configured scm.

You do not need to configure the tagbase tag in release plugin in case you follow "trunk, tags, branches" best practice in your svn repository, [see this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26450262/1920149)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you having a thing like this:

```
+--root (pom.xml)
     +--- module1 (pom.xml)
     +---
```

In the root pom.xml:

```
<project ..>

  <groupId>the.company.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>the-artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  ...
</project>
```

whereas in the childs you should have:

```
<project ..>

  <parent>         
    <groupId>the.company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>the-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>the-artifact-child</artifactId>

</project>
```

For such purposes you should use the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) which handles the updating of the version in root as well in childs. If you don't use maven-release-plugin you can use the [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) which can handle the same things.

Comment: I'm trying out the maven-release-plugin, but I'm getting some errors because of a missing scm property. Do you know what the smallest configuration would be?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and what I did was slightly different than anything suggested so far. Assume that your project has the following folder structure:

```
parent
+-- child1
     +-- child2_of_parent
     +-- child3_of_parent
+-- child4
     +-- child5_of_child4
```

Do note that except for `child5_of_child4`, *all* the rest of the projects have as parent the top level project `parent`. This is regardless of the folder structure.
Parent `pom.xml`:

```
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>...</artifactId>
<version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

All children `pom.xml` except for `child5_of_child4` that has as parent `child4`:

```
 <parent>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <relativePath>../parent</relativePath>
 </parent>
```

You go to the parent directory and change its version from version from `1.1-SNAPSHOT` to `1.2-SNAPSHOT`. Then you do (more details [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-child-modules-mojo.html)):

```
mvn versions:update-child-modules
```

As this is not recursive, it only works on the direct children of your parent project. In other words, all sub-modules will be updated to point to parent `1.2-SNAPSHOT` except for `child5_of_child4`.

Answer (score 1):

In your child pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent.artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>version</version>
    <relativePath>../parent-pom</relativePath>
 </parent>
 <artifactId>child.artifactId</artifactId>
```

Comment: you don't need to specify a relativePath in such circumstances, cause the parent is the default.

Comment: It depends on your directories organization. In some cases, you can have children not included in parent directory so you need to specify relativepath ;)

Answer (score -1):

Just don't put the version in the child poms.  It's inherited automatically.  It will show up as a warning in Eclipse plugin if you edit there.

Comment: Sorry, I get this error when I tried your answer:

 
[ERROR]   The project myGroup:acceptance-tests:[unknown-version] (C:\git\my_app\1.0\my_app\acceptance-tests\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'parent.version' is missing. @ line 8, column 13

Comment: @bakoyaro No.  In <parent> you need to specify version of parent.  You do not specify version of child.