# Maven 3.3 override version

Tags: java, maven, versioning, pom.xml

I am using Maven 3.3.3.  I just upgraded from 3.1.1 and noticed that I can't pass in a version anymore.

pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.hello.world</groupId>
<artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
<version>${VERSION_NUMBER}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<properties>
    <VERSION_NUMBER>LOCAL-ONLY-SNAPSHOT</VERSION_NUMBER>
</properties>
```

mvn package -DVERSION_NUMBER=1.2.3

After upgrading to Maven 3.3.3, I now get the error message: 
[ERROR]     Version must be a constant

My goal is to be able to pass in a version number and never have actual numbers in the pom.xml.  I don't want to use the versions-plugin, as that actually changes the pom.xml to use a specific version number.  No version numbers in source control.

Comment: See this it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981151/warning-on-using-project-parent-version-as-the-version-of-a-module-in-maven-3

Comment: @SubodhJoshi That link still doesn't have an answer relevant to my question.  I still need to figure out how do I use ${buildNumber} from buildnumber-maven-plugin in version?

Comment: I have my doubts that you have updated from a Maven version 3.1.3? Does not exist....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do what you're attempting in the latest versions of maven - the version is so integral to the build process that you must specify it explicitly in your POM.

The only way around it (and I'm not suggesting that this is a good idea) would be to add a pre-processing step before your maven command e.g. using `sed` to modify the POM and set whatever version number you want.

Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'd like to get my CI server (Jenkins) to manage all versioning and releasing, without having any developers worry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one or a combination of the following properties:

```
${revision}, ${changelist}, and ${sha1}.
```

That's simply the reason it does not work.

Comment: Could you explain how this works?  I replaced VERSION_NUMBER with revision, and I get the same error - version must be a constant.