# Dependent project not reading properties from parent POM

Tags: maven

I have the following project structure:

```
Parent
-- Module A
-- Module B
    -- Module C
    -- Module D
```

`Parent` has the following properties:

```
<properties>
    <ModuleA.version>1.8</ModuleA.version>
</properties>
```

In module `C`, I am specifying dependency of `A`, using `${ModuleA.version}`.

`Module D` depends on `Module C`, which in turn depends on `Module A`. Now, when I am running `mvn clean install` on `Module D`, considering that they share the same parent, I am expecting that the properties defined in parent would be available and hence `ModuleA.version` would be resolved to `1.8` and used.

However, the command is failing with the error:

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: ModuleA:jar:${ModuleA.version}
```

Can someone help me with what I am missing here.

In all the modules I am specifying parents correctly.
That is: `Module C` and `Module D` mentions `Module B` as parent. `Module B` and `Module A` mentions `Parent` as parent.

Actual POM's below:
**Parent**:

```
<groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>0.15-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Parent</name>

<properties> 
    <store-version>0.19-SNAPSHOT</store-version> 
    <data-version>0.16-SNAPSHOT</data-version>
</properties>
```

**Data POM**

com.dummy
    parent
    0.15-SNAPSHOT
    ../../parent

**Store POM:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.15-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../parent</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>data</artifactId>
    <version>${data-version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I use mvn clean install for Store project, it finds Data version and gives no errors.

**Source POM**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.15-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../parent</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>source</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

**Source API POM**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>source</artifactId>
    <version>0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>store</artifactId>
    <version>${store.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Source API builds fine, finds proper versions.

**Source WS**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>source</artifactId>
    <version>0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
     <artifactId>source-api</artifactId>
     <version>${project.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

When I try to build source-ws, the build fails with error, ${data-version} not found.

Comment: Please show the pom file ...

Answer (score 0):

I created the following projects according to your description:

```
+- P
+- A  -> parent P
+- B  -> parent P
+- C  -> parent B, depends on A
+- D  -> parent B, depends on C
```

#### `P`'s POM

```
<groupId>so.55374493</groupId>
<artifactId>P</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <ModuleA.version>1.8</ModuleA.version>
    <revision>1.8</revision>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>../A</module>
    <module>../B</module>
</modules>
```

#### `A`'s POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>so.55374493</groupId>
    <artifactId>P</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../P</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>A</artifactId>
<version>${ModuleA.version}</version>
<!-- use the following instead to omit: 
     "[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant." -->
<!-- <version>${revision}</version> -->
```

#### `B`'s POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>so.55374493</groupId>
    <artifactId>P</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../P</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>B</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>../C</module>
    <module>../D</module>
</modules>
```

#### `C`'s POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>so.55374493</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../B</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>C</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>so.55374493</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>${ModuleA.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

#### `D`'s POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>so.55374493</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../B</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>D</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>so.55374493</groupId>
        <artifactId>C</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`mvn install` on `P` and `D` both succeed (where `A` at the former prints [the well-known `[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant.`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1981151/1744774), which can be resolved by [`${revision}` since Maven 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49029661/1744774)).

Can you confirm that your POMs look equally in terms of `<parent>`s, `<properties>` (except `${revision}`), `<version>`s and `<dependencies>`?

Comment: I've added POM's in the description, to give more clarity about the issue.